# need help reading issue listed in stacktrace for an Spring-mvc project

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I've cloned a spring-mvc project and trying to get it running using intelliJ 12. 1.3. I have the stacktrace below, having trouble figuring out why the application is choking. I see that it's not connecting to the db because of the `Connection timed out: connect` error message. I did set up `data source` through the `database` tab, in intelliJ. Also, I set up the datasource connection information in an xml file.

**edit** I've added a data source using the data source in intelliJ

[data source image http://snag.gy/1loae.jpg](http://snag.gy/1loae.jpg)

**also** added connection xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!--  Data Source Setup -->
<bean id="hsqldataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql" />
    <property name="username" value="example" />
    <property name="password" value="example" />
</bean>
<bean id="mysqldataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.71.1:3306/test_dev" />
<property name="username" value="example" />
    <property name="password" value="example" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Division.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Modality.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Score.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/User.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/QaCase.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Review.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Exam.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Patient.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>example/peer-review/domain/hibernatemapping/Role.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="hsqldataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!--  Dao Layer generic config-->    
<bean id="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.GenericDAOHibernateImpl" abstract="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!--  Dao Layer instances -->
<bean id="DivisionDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.DivisionDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="ModalityDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.ModalityDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="ScoreDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.ScoreDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="UserDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.UserDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="ReviewDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.ReviewDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="QaCaseDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.QaCaseDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="ExamDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.ExamDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="PatientDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.PatientDAOHibernateImpl" />
<bean id="RoleDAO" parent="abstractDaoTarget" class="example.peer-review.persistence.hibernate.RoleDAOHibernateImpl" />

<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
<property name="url" value="ldap://example.edu:1234" />
<property name="base" value="" />
<property name="userDn" value="cn=Test1" />
<property name="password" value="Test1" />
<property name="authenticationStrategy" ref="ldapAuthStrat" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthStrat" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.ExternalTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy" />
</beans>
```

**partial stack trace**: below (character limit). Otherwise [full stack trace](http://pastebin.com/7XqPmmFh)

```
C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin\catalina.bat run
[2014-05-19 03:07:18,047] Artifact peerreview:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\.IntelliJIdea12\system\tomcat\Unnamed_peerreview_3"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.53"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58998', transport: 'socket'
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.2\bin\..\.\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;C:\grails\grails-2.2.0\bin;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\bin;.
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 399 ms
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 19, 2014 3:07:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 38 ms
Connected to server
[2014-05-19 03:07:19,087] Artifact peerreview:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
May 19, 2014 3:07:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\manager
15:07:46.254 [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
15:07:46.260 [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
15:07:46.272 [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] WARN  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2209) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173) ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149) ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119) ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81) ~[spring-hibernate-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863) [hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859) [hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870) [hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:822) [spring-hibernate-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:748) [spring-hibernate-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1504) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:459) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:459) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) [spring-context-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381) [spring-web-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [spring-web-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.0.RC1.jar:3.1.0.RC1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1740) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_11]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2132) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar:na]
        ... 90 common frames omitted
15:07:46.289 [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DivisionDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-business.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available
```

Comment: Hi Paul, can you please provide the following to assist us: code to show your DB connection setup in Spring, support DB files, DB Type you are using and its configuration. I will help further when this data is present :)

Comment: thanks Aeseir, I'm using a mysql connection. I've added a connection xml file and an image from my datasource tab.

Comment: What happens if you change the `dataSource` of the `sessionFactory` to `mysqldataSource`?

Comment: I made the change `<property name="dataSource" ref="mysqldataSource" />` but get the same stacktrace

Comment: Your datasource setup does not match the image you're showing so I doubt you're testing the same connection. Is `192.168.12.2:3306` blocked by a firewall?

Comment: sorry bart, I put in an example IP address and forgot ended up using an old table name `dev`. I've updated the post to reflect what my copy looks like for the connection

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace here too -- the question is useless without out and I can't access it from work.

Comment: I pasted the stack trace in the question

Answer (score 1):

Line 147 of the stacktrace indicates that the root cause is that the connection is timing out:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

So, something with your connection isn't happy, but in a way that doesn't just kill the connection immediately.

I would set up a new DB server on your development machine (if possible) to eliminate as much of the network as possible to isolate the issue.

Beyond that, there isn't too much that can be done to figure out what's wrong without knowing a lot more about the networking environment and server configuration.